# Pyajam in debian 7

Tags: python, pip, pyajam

I'm trying to make the installation package python Pyajam

I tried to install for pip, I received an error 4Suite-XML package

```
$ pip install Pyajam

Installing collected packages: pyajam, 4Suite-XML
Running setup.py install for pyajam

Running setup.py install for 4Suite-XML
Usage:
-c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
-c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
-c cmd --help
-c --help-commands
-c --help-packages

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import   
XML/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_'exec'))"     install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-YlpamB-   record/install-  record.txt:
Usage:

-c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
-c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
-c cmd --help
-c --help-commands
-c --help-packages

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

The error appears with the installation of 4Suite-XML package, the dependence      pyajam

I tried to install only 4Suite-XML

```
pip install 4Suite-XML
```

Return the same error

Finally I tried to install by apt

```
apt-get install python-pyajam
apt-get install python-4Suite-XML
```

Unable to find package python-pyajam or python-4Suite-XML

Comment: Please give the exact command line you used when trying to install.

Comment: I tried with, pip install pyajam

Comment: Put the command at the beginning of the output, not in a comment.

Comment: How are you installing the pip package? How you installed pip?

Comment: the package pip this installed for apt-get install python-pip, is working.

The problem is the packet python 4Suite-XML

Comment: This is probably not an especially helpful comment, but the source for 4Suite-XML is still available in unstable, though the binary was removed from Debian years ago. The last release containing it was squeeze. So one can do `apt-get source python-4suite-xml`. However, the source failed to build for me on wheezy amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Compile the package

```
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/4/4Suite-XML/4Suite-XML-1.0.2.tar.bz2

$ tar -xvvf 4Suite-XML-1.0.2.tar.bz2

$ cd 4Suite-XML-1.0.2

$ ./setup.py install


------------------------------------------------------------------------
4Suite-XML version 1.0.2 has been successfully installed!

Python modules (including C extensions)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Executable scripts (for PATH environment variable)
/usr/local/bin

Examples, demos and other miscellaneous data files
/usr/local/share/4Suite

Developer files (regression tests)
/usr/local/lib/4Suite

Text documentation
/usr/local/share/doc/4Suite

HTML documentation
/usr/local/share/doc/4Suite/html
```

Thank you all =]